# How to I execute part of a daily workflow only on Sundays

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

i have one workflow 'wf_OFSLL_WVR_CONV_ERROR_LOG_ARC' which should run only on sunday. i have created one workflow which trigger the this 'wf_OFSLL_WVR_CONV_ERROR_LOG_ARC'workflow only on sunday.so what will be the condition for this to trigger only on sunday

Answer (score 0):

can you schedule the workflow using scheduler?

Edit the workflow > go to scheduler > change schedule according to this pic.
[image: Schedule]

Make sure the workflow runs forever and repeat every week.

EDIT-
per comment,
Let the workflow link run everyday and dont mention any condition. And then add below piece of code into your code so it will kick off worflows only on Sundays.

```
#/bin/sh
if [[ $(date +%u) -eq 7 ]]; then
    echo 'Sunday, time to kick off the infa workflow'
    ## write your pmcmd here
    exit
fi
```

Comment: yes but i want a link condition because i have created a cmd which trigger this workflow so this cmd should trigger only on sunday

Comment: I added the solution.